# Redmine - Database Structure/Normalization

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, redmine

I am using redmine for project management and issue tracking.

I was looking at the database tables and the underlying structure and was wondering if anyone who is VERY experienced with database architecture can comment on the structure.

I am concerned that once there are many users and hundreds (or thousands) of projects (each project containing many issues, with each issue containing many messages, etc.), the database structure could possibly turn out to be a weak point.

- How is the performance impacted by this design?
- I would like to hear about the Pros/cons of how the tables are laid
  out and how the data is separated or normalized, and whether or not
  it might be worth re-structuring.
- What would be the benefits of
  separating the data out to more tables (with less columns per table)

Comment: How do you expect someone to “comment on” the structure, tables, performance, and so on when you haven't shown us the structures, tables, performance, or in fact anything at all?

Comment: if you knew what the question was talking about, you would have most of the facts you just asked about. Are you a DB Admin, architect, or designer in the field?? I can help you find that information if you need it and you are an expert in the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database structure looks typical for an issue/project tracking system. If you can come up with a better structure, I would be very interested in seeing it :).

What you have to remember is that applying normalisation rules are all fine and dandy but if you apply it too much then sometimes you may hit performance problems (and the dreaded de-normalisation hacks start to creep in). In other words, there's a balancing act to be done between some normalisation and hardcore (too much) normalisation.

You would have to have a good reason to re-structure that database model. For example, it could be that for some particular query the database design does not serve the answer in an efficient manner. You could then start asking yourself what other table(s) could be created that would hold the data that I need in an efficient manner for optimal query performance. Also you could ask yourself what other indexes could be in place which will allow for optimal performance.

The fact is that until you have the very high number of users and projects and issues in this database as you predict it is hard to answer those questions. Maybe you could generate the data for some fake users and projects and test out the database to backup your concerns? Remember the adage of Professor Donald Knuth: Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: I guess im thinking of over-normalization. lol.
maybe you could explain what "de-normalization hacks" are? not sure if it is the same as what I am thinking of.